# Subaru Forester - Timing Belt

Tags: subaru, timing-belt, forester, timing

I have a Subaru Forester X Limited AT 2000cc 2AB 2009.

The timing belt requires replacement.

My question is if the Gates TCK304 Timing Belt Component Kit, fits my Subaru?

Comment: When I google Gates TCK304 it says that it does.

Comment: I concur with @DucatiKiller ... I'm showing it as a fit for your vehicle as well, though I'm only showing a 2.5L H4 for the 2009 and not a 2.0L version.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, that should fit

[O'Reilly's  compatibility chart for the Gates TCK304](http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/detail/GATU/TCK304/03978.oap?ck=Search_03978_1432743_-1&pt=03978&ppt=C0141#compatibilityTab_) shows your vehicle under the compatible vehicles.  In addition, [Amazon's compatibility](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002R8HMAY) seems to say the same thing.

Are you sure that you have a 2000cc (2.0L) engine?  The only match I see is the 2.5L for that year and trim.

**Edit:** it turns out that there is a 2.0L version of this car, however it seems to be slightly obscure, and O'Reilly doesn't have it in there car list.

Per the OP's comment: The replacement part is: 13028AA240 for Subaru Forester X Limited  AT 2000cc 2009

Comment: absolutly 100 % sure

Comment: thanks a lot for the comments and suggestions. the replacement part is: 13028AA240 for subaru forester X Limited  AT 2000cc 2009

Comment: When you get the parts do your best to check that they match your existing ones. Mistakes happen and it is far better to detect them before you've torn your car apart!